# Does it make sense to initialize models from the DOM in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, models, backbone.js

backbone.js relies on restful applications to initialize models, but what about progressive enhancement? The data is already in the dom (or some of it), so should my models still make calls the the restful interface even though the html elements exist? Is there another library design that might be better suited for this case?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should not use DOM element to initialize your model with backend data. You have a really nice infrastructure with backbone to not do this. When you rely on the DOM you need to change your javascript whenever the DOM structure change due to design for exemple.

Also do not rely on backbone view to create the model. It must go the other way around, the model dictate the views on the page.

Just add a script element and create your JS objects directly in there. You can initialize collections, single models, etc.

You can do the same with templates or DOM UI building blocks:

```
<script type="text/js-template">
  <!-- Your template as realy do elements or using a js templating engine like _.template-->
</script>
```

Load up your page and have your app play locally.

Comment: One downside of not using the DOM in my opinion is the lack of search engine support in the initial data load.

Comment: Not true. What I said was not to load data based on your dom in your JS. You load the data on the page as JSON (in the header, body or whatever). Your first loaded dom should be all there and your js code just hooks up with it and keep it up to date with the model.

Comment: So the data is rendered server side in two places? (once in the dom, once as JSON in the script)

Comment: That's the best way to avoid flickering and support search engines.

Answer (score 6):

Backbone can handle that pretty well. The way I handle this case is to have a factory model that can receive a DOM node and parse it in order to extract data (id, fields and so on).

If you supply a 'el' option to a [View constructor](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor), backbone won't fetch nor render the model, so you can keep your node as is.

Upon data change, the controller will then sync to the server. You must be careful though to include whatever data your application needs to function whether it's displayed or not.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap

They perform a neat little trick of serializing their models to json when rendering the template server side. I could go either way really.

Comment: @Arthur, this is interesting.  Could you do into more detail about how you go about extracting the data in the DOM to your model?

Comment: @Arthur, I agree this is interesting.  I cannot find anyone else blogging about doing this kind of thing with a JS MVC Framework, and although it makes sense for me to approach website development i'm wondering why no one else is doing it.  Essentially I don't want to do use the single-page app paradigm.